# Editing value of just one cell in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column named ID in a Query, it contains only 0 and 1. Looks like this:

```
  XY     ID    Index
 ---     ----   --
  R       1      0
  R       1      1
  R       1      2
  V       0      3
  V       0      4
```

I want to change the ID column so that the first row has the value 5. Apart from that it is the same column as above.

```
  XY     ID      Index
  ---     ----  ---
  R       5      0
  R       1      1
  R       1      2
  V       0      3
  V       0      4
```

Is there a way to do this? I duplicated the column in Power Query, and then changed the DAX code to

```
    = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed type", "ID2",  IF ([Index] = "0" and Query([ID]) = 
     "1") THEN "5" ELSE [ID])
```

But this doesn't work. I've been struggling to solve this issue for quite some time now, does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change Query[ID] to [ID]
2. Maybe it's an issue with data types, "0" is not the same as 0.